# DevOps shortcut to latest build of a pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a standard url that always shows the latest running build of a particular pipeline?
In this one build Id is needed.
https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/MyPrj/_build/results?buildId=**1029**&view=results

So Always I am forced to go builds list and pick the one on top. Two clicking and two page loads. Would be nice if I can always reach here on one click.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes.

You can go the latest running build of a particular pipeline by clicking below url:

`https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_build/latest?definitionId={definitionId}`

The DefinitionID is id of the pipeline. Yon can get it on the address bar when you click the pipeline.

[image]

Update:

Above url is not documented. I just tested it on my pipeline and found it was working.

If it was working in your case, You can click this url `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_build?definitionId={definitionId}` to go to the pipeline history page. But you will have to manual pick the one on top in this way.

You can also [submit a use voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) for this standard url to microsoft development team. Hope they add this to azure devops pipeline.

Comment: What is a definition id? Any sample?

Comment: The definitionId is the ID of the pipeline. You can click on a pipeline, you will see it on the address bar. See above screenshot.

Comment: It is not working as expected. When I give https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myPrj/_build/latest?definitionId=34, I get is an older build of the same pipeline. https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myPrj/_build/results?buildId=1007&view=results. When the latest really is https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myPrj/_build/results?buildId=1031&view=results (both these have passed) and in between there are 25 failed builds.

Comment: It is weird, it is working for my pipeline. Every pipeline run has a build id. Did you check the buildid to make sure if it an older build above url redirected? eg. `https://dev.azure.com/org/proj/_build/results?buildId=5292&view=results`

Comment: yes I rechecked. It is always redirecting to the old one.

Comment: If above url was not working, You can click this url `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_build?definitionId={definitionId}` to go to the pipeline history page, But you need manual pick the one on top. You can also submit a user voice. See above update

Comment: Or you can write some batch scripts to call [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the latest build id and then open the url. You can save the script file on the desktop, next time you can just click on the batch file to view the latest build. But this preparation work is a litter complicated.